# Is JavaFx suitable for creating online multiplayer board/card games?

Tags: java, javafx

In JavaFx i can easy create animations, moving pieces etc., but as far as i see there is better to write program logic and communication in java. Worst i see at the moment is calling javafx part as a result of data incoming from server. Is there any convenient way to do it or its better to change to other technology (flex, qt?) assuming it is not important if program will run in browser or outside as a standalone application?

I just started to learn javafx but can drop it and move to other technology and consider c++ + wxWidgets or Qt which im more comforatable with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaFx is certainly appropriate for that, but for the programming logic, the idea is to do it in Java (JavaFx is designed to work well calling java methods and classes). If you are not comfortable with Java, then it might not be the best choice - it depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

JavaFx is really Sun's (now Oracle's) last best hope of getting some traction on Java on the desktop (I say that because if this fails, I don't see them trying again, but who knows?). It isn't going that well, but if you like JavaFx, and want the distribution improvements that come having executable that doesn't need to be compiled separately for each platform, then it is certainly a viable option.

Comment: What im expecting is: easy of creating user interface with animations (javafx is definitely good at this point), two way server client comuniacation (here i have a feeling javafx is weak and only workarounds with underlaying java can help).

Comment: @piniu, JavaFx has full access to the underlying java API, so the communication should be fine. I don't know if you could do it in 100% JavaFx, or why you would want to, but JavaFx won't suddenly stop working for the animation just because you need some Java glue code.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying technology is probably less important than just being able to make the game.  If you're going to distribute it there might be some question, but at the end of the day no one framework (if you will) is definitively better than any other for the general task of "making games."

Using what you know, you'll be that much more likely to finish the project.  The pattern I see far too frequently is that people spend too much time deciding between languages and APIs and all of that when any number of them are Good Enough.  Once you finish, porting to another technology should be straight forward, if you even need to in the first place.

Good luck.

Comment: Its not general 'making games' task, its narrowed to board/card games and it is important to distinguish it. As they are turn based efficiency on client side is not important at all. I have about 30-40% of engine finished (c++) and it can be easy ported to java at the moment. I should decide if i will continue in c++ (it will be horror write nice GUI in wxWidgets) or rewrite in java and will write GUI in javafx. What im wondering most is if javafx and java can give me easy and nice two-way client server communication. I suppose it can be hard.

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually see why this should be that hard. It's pretty easy to use Java classes and JavaFX, and if performance really doesn't matter, you probably could write even the application logic in JavaFX (remember, it's a full-blown programming language). Maybe posting this question in the official Su... err, Oracle forums will help you further, as there are always some people involved in developing JavaFX around.